# Warning C4244 \ '=': conversion from 'int' to 'char', possible loss of data?

Tags: c++, c++11

When writing a program for solving a puzzle, I encountered a warning in the following snippet:

```
std::string str = "hello";

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    str[i] = toupper(str[i]); //make every letter capital       
//  ^^ warning
```

I'm getting a warning on the last line above.

> Warning C4244 \ '=': conversion from 'int' to 'char', possible loss of data?

Is there any way to get rid of this warning?

Comment: You need to **read the documentation** for `toupper` to understand why it returns `int` so that you can decide what, if anything, to do about this warning. There **is** a reason for that return type, and blithely casting to `char` without knowing what's going on would be a serious mistake.

Comment: Note: I reduced your code to a [mcve]. Why? Well, the fact that you were doing a palindrom program really doesn't have anything to do with the warning. Also, no need for an introduction :) **Always try to make your questions as short as possible, but not too short, i.e. don't leave anything out!**

Comment: @Rakete1111: Would have been an MCVE with includes and a `main`, but otherwise good job!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, for 3 lines of code, I think having a main function + includes is a bit overkill. But thanks :)

Comment: It's okay here because you did it and because there's not much room for ambiguity, but an MCVE must be complete (that's the "C") because who knows what else the OP was doing to alter the results, that wasn't shown. There's also the "reproduce with a quick copy/paste" factor.

Comment: @Rakete1111 ... Thanks I will be careful about that.

Answer (score 9):

Cast the `str[i]` to a char explicitly like this:

```
str[i] = (char)toupper(str[i]);
```

Or:

```
str[i] = static_cast<char>(toupper(str[i]));
```

To make the operation more C++ friendly. `std::toupper` returns an int, which makes the compiler complain. By casting the return value, you tell the compiler you know what you are doing.

As a side note, I recommend using `boost::to_upper()` on the string at once, like this:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <string>

std::string str = "hello";

boost::to_upper(str); //Is HELLO

std::string newstr = boost::to_upper_copy<std::string>("hello"); //is HELLO
```

Comment: Thanks @Arnav ... implemented the casting. I should have checked the doc of toUpper

Comment: The function `std::transform` can also be used to convert strings to all upper or lower case.

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly cast it to a `char`:

```
str[i] = (char)toupper(str[i]);
```

`toupper()` is defined as returning an `int`, and that's why your compiler is yelling at you. In this case, you know exactly what you're doing, you just need to convince the compiler, a little bit.

Comment: Using a C-style cast isn't a good thing and should be avoided most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and since the code I was working on was using -Wall, I was getting warnings about int to char possible loss of data.  Now I could have gone with a simple:

```
std::string s = "Hello World";

for (char& c : s)
{
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z)
       c &= 0x20;
}
```

But this was **ONLY** because I could guarantee that what I was dealing with was pure ASCII and would never be anything else.  As someone else has mentioned, it's probably better to go with *std::transform()* and *::toupper()* the only issue I have with their particular answer is that they recommend turning off warnings that you'd get from using this approach.  You'll still get them because *::toupper()* and *::tolower()* both return int from their conversions.

So what I ended up with to get the best of both worlds, was to cast the return code of *::toupper* like below.  This means I don't have to disable warnings for this conversion.

```
std::string s = "Hello World";
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](int c) -> char { return static_cast<char>(::tolower(c)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

`toupper` needs, in full generality, to deal with EOF, which is why it takes an `int` as the parameter and returns an `int`.

I'd be inclined to bury this complexity and write

```
#include <algorithm>
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);
```

instead, and switch off the warning for compilation of this code.

Comment: How does `transform` solve the problem you mentioned? All you did is to mask the loop.